# sql query to find out sum of the slots for each department

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Table **tempslotsassignedfordept** as below

```
DEPT        ScheduledStartDate          ScheduledEndDate            TotalSlots

DevEng      2012-07-17 00:00:00.000     2012-08-28 00:00:00.000     39
DevEng      2012-07-17 00:00:00.000     2012-08-31 00:00:00.000     18
DevEng      2012-07-18 00:00:00.000     2012-08-29 00:00:00.000     9
DevEng      2012-07-19 00:00:00.000     2012-08-30 00:00:00.000     40
Prod        2012-07-19 00:00:00.000     2012-08-30 00:00:00.000     8
Rel         2012-07-19 00:00:00.000     2012-08-30 00:00:00.000     19
Rel         2012-07-19 00:00:00.000     2013-08-15 00:00:00.000     1
```

I have to capture the above sum of the totalslots of each department. if there are serial 3days exists for a department.
If you see the above table, **there is department deveng has the serial three scheduled start dates as 2012-07-17,2012-07-18,2012-07-19.**

I'm trying to see the resuls by using the below query, please could you help what is the more implementations to see the exact result?

```
SELECT  Tmain.DepartmentCode, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Tmain.ScheduledStartDate, 101) 'ScheduledStartDate',
                SUM(Tmain.TotalSlots) 'Tmain.TotalSlots',T1Sub.TotalSlots 'T1SubTotalSlots', T2Sub.TotalSlots 'T2SubTotalSlots'

                FROM    tempSlotsAssignedForDept Tmain

                        INNER   JOIN (Select    DATEADD(DAY,1,T1.ScheduledStartDate) 'ScheduledStartDate',SUM(T1.TotalSlots) 'TotalSlots'
                                        FROM    tempSlotsAssignedForDept  T1 
                                                INNER JOIN tempSlotsAssignedForDept Tmain                    
                                                ON (T1.ScheduledStartDate = dateadd(day, -1, tmain.ScheduledStartDate ) and  
                                                    T1.DepartmentCode = tmain.DepartmentCode)
                                                GROUP BY T1.ScheduledStartDate ) T1Sub                        
                        ON Tmain.ScheduledStartDate = T1Sub.ScheduledStartDate

                        INNER   JOIN (Select    DATEADD(DAY,2,T2.ScheduledStartDate) 'ScheduledStartDate',SUM(T2.TotalSlots) 'TotalSlots'
                                        FROM    tempSlotsAssignedForDept  T2 
                                                INNER JOIN tempSlotsAssignedForDept Tmain                    
                                                ON (T2.ScheduledStartDate = dateadd(day, -2, tmain.ScheduledStartDate ) and  
                                                    T2.DepartmentCode = tmain.DepartmentCode)
                                                GROUP BY T2.ScheduledStartDate ) T2Sub                
                        ON Tmain.ScheduledStartDate = T2Sub.ScheduledStartDate

                GROUP BY    Tmain.DepartmentCode,Tmain.ScheduledStartDate,T1Sub.TotalSlots , T2Sub.TotalSlots 
                ORDER BY Tmain.ScheduledStartDate
```

The Outof the Above query is

```
DepartmentCode  ScheduledStartDate  Tmain.TotalSlots    T1SubTotalSlots T2SubTotalSlots
DevEng          07/19/2012          40                  9               57
Prod            07/19/2012          8                   9               57
Rel             07/19/2012          20                  9               57
```

The final result should be as below.
Becuase, departments prod and rel don't have the series of scheduledstartdate for 3days

```
DepartmentCode  ScheduledStartDate  Tmain.TotalSlots    T1SubTotalSlots T2SubTotalSlots
DevEng          07/19/2012          40                  9               57
```

please help.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really make sense how you're describing it.  You're trying to sum Tmain.TotalSlots and yet in your final result you're showing Tmain.TotalSlots which is 40hrs?  shouldn't you want it to be 80 hours? Please clarify

Comment: @jeschafe,   Yes, Tmain.TotalSlots should come as 40, because DepartDev only has the 3serial days.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'serial'?

Comment: Serial means, Please find in table tempslotsassignedfordept , there is department deveng has the serial three scheduled start dates as 2012-07-17,2012-07-18,2012-07-19.

Comment: What do you want to have happen if there are _more_ than three consecutive days?  Only the last three get counted?  All of them?  Count every three days (and what happens to any leftovers)?  Only if three days exactly exist?

Comment: So if a department has two entries on day one, two entries for day two, and two entries for day three, they would have entries for three serial days, right?  Which of there day three totalslots values would you want?

Comment: All, Please find the below answer. Thank You for being with me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer you're looking for:

```
Select * from 
(
Select DepartmentCode,ScheduledStartDate,[Tmain.TotalSlots]
,(Select SUM(T1.TotalSlots) from tempSlotsAssignedForDept  T1 where t1.departmentCode=a.DepartmentCode
and T1.ScheduledStartDate = dateadd(day, -1, a.ScheduledStartDate )) T1SubTotalSlots 
,(Select SUM(T1.TotalSlots) from tempSlotsAssignedForDept  T1 where t1.departmentCode=a.DepartmentCode
and T1.ScheduledStartDate = dateadd(day, -2, a.ScheduledStartDate )) T2SubTotalSlots 
from 
(
SELECT  Tmain.DepartmentCode, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Tmain.ScheduledStartDate, 101) ScheduledStartDate,
SUM(Tmain.TotalSlots) 'Tmain.TotalSlots'
--,(Select SUM(T1.TotalSlots) from tempSlotsAssignedForDept t1 where t1.DepartmentCode=tmain.departmentcode 
--and T1.ScheduledStartDate = dateadd(day, -1, tmain.ScheduledStartDate ))
FROM    tempSlotsAssignedForDept Tmain
GROUP BY    Tmain.DepartmentCode,Tmain.ScheduledStartDate
) a) b where [Tmain.TotalSlots] is not null and T1SubTotalSlots is not null and T2SubTotalSlots is not null
```

Comment: No disuccssions! Direct Answer, I like it. Thank You